# I cannot select the input submit button inside form tags on CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, input, submit

As the reference on the subject, I cannot select the submit although I tried to change the code on CSS by using nth-child, nth-type-of, [type=submit] and so on. If anyone knows how we can access in the element on css, please help me out.

```css
#subButton{
      padding: 2% 7%;
      background: #e32b7a;
      text-align: center;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 10pt;
      letter-spacing: 0.02em;
      transition: all .3s;
      position: relative;
      margin: 24px 0 0 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #subButton:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: none;
      background-color: #f42988;
      color: white;
      z-index: -2;
    }
    #subButton:before {
      content: '';
      color: cornsilk;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 0%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #db257a;
      text-align: left;
      transition: all .3s;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    #subButton:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }
    #subButton:hover:before {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<section class="newsLetter">
          <h1><i>Better design info gives you better inspiration.</i></h1>
          <form method="post" action="send2.php" class="content">
                  <div><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required></div>
                  <div><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required></div>
                  <div><input type="submit" id="subButton" value="Subscribe"></div>
          </form>
</section>
```

Comment: You can use input[type=submit] or input:nth-child(3) instead of #subButton.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Select the element to restyle it ? It should work if you use #subButton and put css under rest of the css

Comment: @Valentino KoZinec  I was creating a button which has a slide-in color effect ! I solved the problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input[type=submit]` or `input:nth-child(3)` instead of `#subButton`.